# Average of function defined on cantor set

Tags: measure-theory, summation, lebesgue-measure, average, cantor-set

Suppose we have $P: A\cap[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, where $A$ is the Cantor set. I want to define and find the average of $P$ to give a result between the infimum and supremum of $P$'s range.

Obviously we cannot use the Lebesgue measure, as the average would be zero. Instead, we need a new definition.

My intuition is, as the iterations increase the length of remaining intervals approach zero. This means the intervals approach singularities or points.

To find the average we need the beginning and end-points of defined intervals in current iterations which the defined intervals will approach in the next iterations.

First Iteration:

${0,1/3,2/3,1}$

Second Iteration:

$0,1/9,2/9,3/9,6/9,7/9,8/9,9/9$

Third Iteration:

$0/27,1/27,2/27,3/27,6/27,7/27,8/27,9/27,18/27,19/27,20/27,21/27,24/27,25/27,26/27,27/27$

The numerators for each iteration go in a pattern which I call Cantor's Integers

$0,1,2,3,6,7,8,9,18,19,20,21,24,25,26,27,54,55,56,57,60,61,62,63,...$

We will define them as ${C}_n$. For every iteration $k$, the definition of average for $P$ should be

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2^{k+1}} P\left({C_n}/{3^k}\right)}{2^{k+1}}$$

How do we find the exact value of this sum? How do we apply my definition of average to other uncountable sets with measure zero?

I want to find some P which is nontrivial, intuitive for certain 'simple' sets, and which produces interesting results (which can be retrospectively reconciled with intuition) for more complicated sets such as the Cantor (set but possibly others) such that it in some way gives a sense of an average.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to intuit the Cantor distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution)

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I was hoping to solve this sum in terms of integration. Using Mathematica I found polynomial $P$ may give a closed form but other functions may not.

Comment: If $\mu$ denotes the Cantor distribution, then the above expression converges to $\int_A P\textrm{d}\mu$ for any continuous $P$ by Dominated Convergence.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou But according to Lebesgue measure, the cantor set has a measure of zero. I want a definition of average that is between the infinum and supremum of $P$'s range.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou For example, if $P(x)=x^2$ what would the average be? It should be $3/8$.

Comment: But if $I_{n,k}=[C_n3^{-k},(C_n+1)3^{-k}]$, then the Lesbegue measure of $I_{n,k}$ is $3^{-k}$, whereas you've rescaled by $2^{-k}$, which is the Cantor distribution measure of $I_{n,k}$. For the integral of polynomials, check the link above, it does contain the calculation.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I haven’t studied probability theory. I’m not sure what var means. Can you answer my question full showing for $P=x^2$ how to answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I_0=[0,1]$ and define $I_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}I_n\cup (\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}I_n)$. Then $A=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$. Thus, we get the self-similarity $A=\frac{1}{3}A\cup (\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}A)$. Let $\lambda$ be the Lesbegue measure and define $\mu_n(B)=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n \lambda(B\cap I_n)$ to be the uniform measure on $I_n$. Then, there exists a measure $\mu$ called the Cantor distribution such that $\mu([a,b])=\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu_n([a,b])$ for all $a,b$. The usual arguments for its existence are either showing that the distribution functions $F_n$ of $\mu_n$ converge uniformly to the distribution function of some probability measure or appealing to Alaoglu's theorem to get a subsequential weak limit, which must necessarily be unique by the uniqueness theorem for finite measures. Note that it's clear from self-similarity that
$$
\int_{\frac{1}{3}A} f(x)\textrm{d}\mu=\mu\left(\frac{1}{3}A\right)\int_A f(x/3)\textrm{d}\mu=\frac{1}{2}\int_A f(x/3)\textrm{d}\mu
$$
and that the measure restricted to $[0,1]$ is invariant under translation by $\frac{1}{3}$ mod $\mathbb{Z}$.

Thus, applying the self-similarity of $A$ again, we see that

\begin{align}
\int_A x^2\textrm{d}\mu &=\int_{\frac{1}{3}A} x^2\textrm{d}\mu+\int_{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}A} \left(x-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\right)^2\textrm{d}\mu \\
&=2\int_{\frac{1}{3}A} x^2\textrm{d}\mu+\int_{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}A}\frac{4}{9}+\frac{4}{3}\left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)\textrm{d}\mu \\
&=\int_A \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^2\textrm{d}\mu+ \frac{4}{3}\int_{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}A}\left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\textrm{d}\mu\\
&=\frac{1}{9} \int_A x^2\textrm{d}\mu+\frac{2}{9}\int_A x\textrm{d}\mu+\frac{2}{9}
\end{align}
Now, since the measure $\mu(B+\frac{1}{2})=\mu(-B+\frac{1}{2})$ and $\mu$ is a probability measure, we get that $\int_A x\textrm{d}\mu=\frac{1}{2}$ and thus, we see that
$$
\frac{8}{9}\int_A x^2\textrm{d}\mu=\frac{3}{9},
$$
implying, indeed, that $\int_A x^2\textrm{d}\mu=\frac{3}{8}$. Similarly, you will be able to integrate any polynomial recursively.

Comment: How come you can’t find closed form for non-polynomial $P$. Has any of this ever been considered an average of the Cantor set?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't do integration explicitly for most functions with respect to most measures.

Comment: And what do you mean by an average? It's a measure... it gives integrals. Works the same as any other measure.

Comment: I mean is there functions other than polynomials where the integral is explicit. Is the average you described well-known in mathematics.

Comment: Maybe. I don't know that it's very interesting. The distribution is a pretty common example of a weird measure.

Comment: It's an example of an atomless measure which is singular with the Lesbegue measure.

Comment: How do we generalize this atomless measure to other uncountable sets with Lebesgue measure zero so the average of $P$ is non-zero.

Comment: This only really works for self-similar sets. I don't think there's a reason why arbitrary uncountable null-sets should have a natural measure if they don't have some sort of shift-invariance or the like.

Comment: One reason giving the average of $P$ a non-zero value between its infimum and supernum. As you see, the average of $P$ defined on the cantor set is not the same as the average of $P$ defined on set in dense in intervals with positive lebesgue measure. The same should apply to any arbitrary uncountable null-sets.

Comment: When defining your naïve averages on the Cantor set, you're *explicitly* using that certain sets are "equally" big. If your given uncountable set doesn't carry such a notion naturally, it seems hard to define anything resembling natural Riemann sums.

Comment: I’m not saying that cantor sets are equally big all I’m saying is the intended definition of average is the mean of the range not $\mathbb{R}$ so a measure that helps give the average should be between the infimum and supernum of Ps range.

Comment: Yes... given that such a measure exists, you'd be right. But I'm saying that when constructing the measure for the Cantor Set, we can look for a measure such that $\mu(3^{-k} A)=2^{-k}$ for every $k$ and satisfies some form of translation invariance. That's instrumental to the entire construction. If you don't have something like that, there's no good reason for a natural measure to exist.

Comment: One more thing, are there uncountable null sets with no shift invariance. I wasn’t able to find examples. If so, could we defined a general measure where the average of $P$ on these sets are undefined and the average of $P$ on other sets are between $P$’s infimum and supremum?

Comment: $+1$. But why the decreasing factor $2^{-n}$ in the definition of $\mu_n$? If we take $B=[0,1]$, we get $\lambda(B\cap I_n)=\left(\frac23\right)^n$, so for this to have a non-zero limit we'd have to define $\mu_n(B)=\left(\frac32\right)^n\lambda(B\cap I_n)$? Or am I missing something there?

Comment: @Joriki Thank you for pointing out that the normalisation was off. Of course, we just want each $\mu_n$ to be a probability measure. The part of the original statement that should be taken seriously is that $\mu_n$ is the uniform measure on $I_n$.